# Bypass process cannot access the file because it it is being used by another process net maui

Tags: c#, .net, file, maui

I have implemented a functionality that allows user to change their profile picture in my app from the SettingsPage.

The profile picture is locally existing in under the name "profile.jpg"

The problem is that after selecting the new picture and Copying the new picture to "profile.jpg" with overwriting enabled, it gives me this error:

```
'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Mess\AppData\Local\2b81b8b3-3ce3-42f9-ad01-256194f0daaf\images\profile.jpg' because it is being used by another process.'
```

**SettingsPage.xaml.cs**:

```
public async void OnSaveButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Saving user data in DB
        UsersData usersData = new UsersData();
          await usersData.UpdateUserData(currentUser.user_id, fNameTxt.Text,
                           lNameTxt.Text,
                           emailTxt.Text,
                           phoneTxt.Text,
                           bDayPicker.Date,
                           double.Parse(heightTxt.Text),
                           double.Parse(objectiveTxt.Text));
        //Updating profile Pic
        if (picChanged)
        {
            File.Copy(profile_picture_file.FullPath, localFolder + "/profile.jpg", true);
            await uploadProfilePictureToFTP(profile_picture_file, currentUser.secret_id);
        }
    }
```

Now, my thoughts is that the file is used only on the Profile Page on the Image control where the profile picture is displayed, probably this is why there is this conflict.

**Profile.xaml.cs**:

```
 protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        
        //Test case
         UsersData usersData = new UsersData();
            currentUser = await usersData.findUserByMailAsync("faat"); //just to test with test user
      
        await pictureController.assingUser(currentUser);
        //picture models scrab from database (picName,picDate...)
       if (pictureModels==null) pictureModels = await pictureController.ScrabPicturesFromDB(currentUser);
        //Getting profile pic
        if (pageCounter == 0)
        {
            PicturesController.setLocalFolder(currentUser);
            local_image_folder = PicturesController.localFolder;
            if (!Directory.Exists(local_image_folder))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(local_image_folder);
            if (File.Exists(local_image_folder + "/profile.jpg"))
            {
                profilePic.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(local_image_folder + "/profile.jpg");
                profilePicExists = true;
            }
            
        }
        //check download missing pics
        Task.Run(async () => {

            await checkPicturesAsync();

            Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
            {
                GalleryControl.BackgroundColor = Colors.Green;
                WeightButton.BackgroundColor = Colors.Green;
                TimeLapseButton.BackgroundColor = Colors.Green;
                if (!profilePicExists)
                {
                    profilePic.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(local_image_folder + "/profile.jpg");
                }
                  });
            });
    }
```

So this is the code to check and download missing pictures and most importantly, the profile picture.

I have added this code onto the Profile page code

```
//Switching profile pics
        if (File.Exists(local_image_folder +"/profile2.jpg")) {
            profilePic.Source = "";
            File.Copy(local_image_folder + "/profile2.jpg", local_image_folder + "/profile.jpg", true);
            File.Delete(local_image_folder + "/profile2.jpg");
        }
```

I thought maybe I could stop using the file then replacing them after copying the new profile picture into "profile2.jpg" but it still gave me same error.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=the+process+cannot+access+the+file+because+it+is+being+used+by+another+process+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: I am aware of that my friend, I did my research, I understand the  reason why it happens, I don't understand why it is happening in this specific situation. What's the point of your comment taking into consideration that each process in use case has different scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First try:**
Creating "profile2.jpg" with the new profile picture and then deleting the "profile.jpg" with the old picture when the app gets restarted
It worked but the profile picture was not being updated although the file was correctly updated and i figured out that it was due to cache.

**So I came up with a final solution:**
Creating a file with a random name ("profil+timestamp.jpg") and after that deleting the old file and setting a preference with the new name to be able to track the profile picture.
Now the cache does not have a history of the file's bytes as i suppose, so it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

> "... probably this is why there is this conflict*" + "I understand the reason why [that error] happens."

Do you understand that you can't overwrite "profile.jpg" while it (the old version) is being displayed? If I understand your code, that is what you have done.

- If the image is visible (is used as an Image's Source), don't touch the file it came from. Its still in use. This is to ensure image can rapidly re-display if needed.

Make sure the UI has released "profile.jpg", before overwriting it:

```cs
Dispatcher.Dispatch( async() =>
    profilePic.Source = null;
    // Make sure UI code runs, so old Source is released.
    await Task.Delay(100);

    // ... User interaction to select/download new profile pic ...

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // This code should NOT touch "profile.jpg"; that is done below.
        // ... background code if needed, for lengthy task such as download ...

        // If the above is successful, use the result.
        File.Delete("profile.bak");
        File.Move("profile.jpg", "profile.bak");
        try
        {
            // ... code to update "profile.jpg" ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Something went wrong. Restore old pic.
            File.Move("profile.bak", "profile.jpg");
        }
    }

    // We've finished Task.Run; now back on MainThread (Dispatcher).
    // Be sure to do this even if user cancels their update!
    profilePic.Source = "profile.jpg";
}
```

Unfortunately there is no event that tells us "UI has finished updating".
Best we can do is relinquish MainThread for awhile, using Delay.
The assumption is that once UI code starts running, it will release Source before our code continues.

---

**An alternative approach** is to avoid touching "profile.jpg" until the NEXT time the page appears. Do this by using a different file location for the duration of this page.

- Save new image to "profile2.jpg", and set image source to that.
- Next time that page appears, look for "profile2.jpg". If it exists, BEFORE page displays, delete old profile and rename "profile2.jpg" to "profile.jpg". That is, do this at a "safe" moment.
- If user makes a second change while page is showing, name that "profile3.jpg". Since "2" is showing, you can safely delete the original "profile.jpg" now.